# random.shuffle only works once

Tags: python, arrays, shuffle

My task is to shuffle numbers and that append to array. My program is shuffling it but only once.

```
order = []
population = []
i = 0
for i in range(i,M):
    order.append(i)
i = 0
for i in range(i,10):
    random.shuffle(order)
    population.append(order)

my input = [[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2]]
expected input = [[0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: who is `M` ? can you add your full code ?

Answer (score 1):

you are appending references to the same list `order` so you have one list in the final result, you could use:

```
for i in range(i,10):
    new_o = order.copy()
    random.shuffle(new_o)
    population.append(new_o)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use copy because you are appending the same reference over and over again, so you are actually shuffling `order` but it is affecting to every instance in `population`

```
import random
import copy

order = []
population = []

i = 0
for i in range(i,M):
    order.append(i)
i = 0
for i in range(i,10):
    random.shuffle(order)
    population.append(copy.deepcopy(order))

print(population)
```